# How to maintain Image Quality during Drawing in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using the following code to merge 2 images in C#,

```
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:/Users/A/Desktop/A.jpg"), 0, 0, 128, 128);
            g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:/Users/A/Desktop/B.png"), 12, 12, 77, 77);
        }
        image.Save("C:/Users/A/Desktop/C.jpg");
```

But the quality of image is distracting. Any way to maintain image quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPEG file format uses lossy compression.

If you want to preserve quality, save as PNG instead, which is lossless.

Comment: Thanks, actually another issue was that I was not using the exact width and height. It resolved. Thanks.